# How do I handle WindowsImpersonationContext with HttpListener?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, httplistener

This may have been asked previously a slightly different way, but I have not yet satisfied myself completely.

With **Visual Studio 2013, Windows 7, and a small C#/.NET 4.0** project, I am using an HttpListener to build a tiny web server in order to host some simple services and pages.  Part of an upgrade to the existing project here was to start using integrated windows authentication.

One of the services this project offers is a way to connect to a SQL database - in order to run some canned updates.  Using WindowsImpersonationContext and the correct HttpListener startup parameters, I was easily able to "impersonate" the authenticated user (via NTLM).  Like so:

```
identity = (System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)context.User.Identity;

using (System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext wic = identity.Impersonate())
{
    doListenerCallback(context, lentry, true, identity);
}
```

The idea is that the credentials of the user accessing the web page is what's used to open the database connection. So this code is fine, and it gives me back an object, and all seems well.

Everything works correctly **until** I run this project (it is hosted inside a console app) using a **regular** user account (non-administrator).  Impersonation still appears to happen, but my appdomain no longer allows assembly loading.  I get stuff like this:

```
fact = System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlClient");
```

Results in:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Data.OracleClient, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. Either a
>   required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided
>   impersonation level is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070542)

And I can't seem to do anything to get beyond this.  I read elsewhere that it might be because a low priv account can't impersonate an admin account, at least without a UAC prompt.

If that is true, how does IIS manage to do this?  Because I've done a lot of crazy ASP.Net stuff with impersonation, and never encountered this before.

We can certainly run this tool with an admin service account.  But it just seems silly to do that - if impersonation exists, and it exists exactly for this kind of purpose, I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong and why it isn't working.

Comment: I've run into this problem recently as well, and never got a clear solution. I think it might have to do with the security bits set on the user attempting to perform the impersonation. I don't think you have to be admin, but you do have to be a user that has the right role. It's definitely weird that the Impersonate() call succeeds even though it's truely failed.

Comment: Check out this documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375497(v=vs.85).aspx. One requirement is that the user have the SeImpersonatePrivilege privilege.

Comment: And if you figure it out, do be sure to post an answer for the rest of the world :)

Comment: I think you gave me the luck I needed

Comment: I agree, the fact the impersonation call is not really succeeding gives you a false positive.  The impersonate call needs to either fail in this case or give back some kind of status code you can check for partial impersonation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I have found the answer to this.  Using antiduh's concept, I found this page:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821546

> Some Programs That Use Impersonation May Not Work Correctly After You
>   Install Windows 2000 SP4
>
> After you install Windows 2000 Service Pack 4 (SP4) on your computer,
>   **some programs that use impersonation may not work correctly**.
>
> This issue may occur in situations when the user account that is used
>   to run the program does not have the "Impersonate a client after
>   authentication" user right.

So that put me on that trail.  That let me here
http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/11/25/fun-with-the-kerberos-delegation-web-site.aspx

> Note  This step is done to allow the IISKerbSvc (application pool
>   identity) the ability to impersonate the user on the web server. **If
>   you look at the computer’s user right assignments you will see
>   Impersonate a client after authentication** and the IIS_WPG group is
>   added there by default.

Oh, ok.  So I dove down into my local security policy for my service user account, and this feature was **not** turned on for that account.

But once I added it... it worked!  :)

[image: Working Example]

Notice my "wwtest" user account explicitly added here.  Once I logged off/on, everything clicked into place.

So here is the answer.  In order for impersonation to *really* work, you have to be a local  administrator, or running as one of the built-in service accounts that already has that flag on, OR you have to go in here and turn this on

Comment: @jgauffin - You'll want to see this, once I finish http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241365/client-server-authentication-using-sspi