# Trouble getting a Kerberos service token

Tags: c#, authentication, kerberos

I'm trying to get a Kerberos ticket using the following code:

```
public static byte[] GetToken(string username, string password, string domain)
{
    using (var domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
    {
        string spn = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username).UserPrincipalName;
        var provider = new KerberosSecurityTokenProvider(spn, TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation, new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain));
        var token = provider.GetToken(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)) as KerberosRequestorSecurityToken;
        return token.GetRequest();
    }
}
```

My problem is the provider.GetToken() method throws a SecurityTokenValidationException with the message "The NetworkCredentials provided were unable to create a Kerberos credential, see inner exception for details". The inner exception reads "Authenticating to a service running under a user account which requires Kerberos multilegs, is not supported". Any thoughts?

I got my code from this thread and it seems it worked in this guy's case: [How to get Service Token from Kerberos using SSPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818333/how-to-get-service-token-from-kerberos-using-sspi)

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this?

Comment: Not really. I ended up calling the unmanaged functions in SSPI to get the token. There is a very good example on pinvoke.net. You need to look for AcquireCredentialsHandle and InitializeSecurityContext functions.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I assume you mean this one:
http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/secur32/InitializeSecurityContext.html

Comment: Yep. That's it.