Http call using UseDefaultCredentials fails after upgrade to .NET 8
The following code works using .NET 6.0, but fails with .NET 8.0:
var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true });
var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://example.com/endpoint");
var response = client.Send(message);

The endpoint being called is third party code that I have no control over.
The error returned is Authentication validation failed with error - InvalidToken.
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Authentication validation failed with error - InvalidToken.
   at System.Net.Http.AuthenticationHelper.SendWithNtAuthAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Uri authUri, Boolean async, ICredentials credentials, Boolean isProxyAuth, HttpConnection connection, HttpConnectionPool connectionPool, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.AuthenticationHelper.SendWithAuthAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Uri authUri, Boolean async, ICredentials credentials, Boolean preAuthenticate, Boolean isProxyAuth, Boolean doRequestAuth, HttpConnectionPool pool, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandlerStage.Send(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandlerStage.Send(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.Metrics.MetricsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandlerStage.Send(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Send(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Send(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Send(HttpRequestMessage request)

My tests have been running under windows. They seem to work correctly under both dotnet 6 and 8 when running under WSL.

What is the error?

What's the difference between .net 6 and .net 8 application? Do you use the same authentication schema, did the user has the permission to access the remote endpoint?

@SoftwareDveloper: I've added the error information to the question.

@BrandoZhang: Code is exactly the same. The only difference is changing the dotnet version. The user has permission and the call works when using dotnet 6.

Which authentication schema you have used? Windows Auth? You are using the Kerberos  or else?

Seems like a coincidental error. Did the token provider change coincidentally?

Are there any redirections involved? HttpClient - Kerberos authentication fails after a redirect · Issue #89300 · dotnet/runtime

Please see this link for more help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818333/how-to-get-service-token-from-kerberos-using-sspi.

What if check packets being sent in Wireshark or other packet capturing tool, what is the difference between .NET 6 and 8?
